# Unable to pick gallery image from Fragment

Tags: android, imagebutton, android-gallery

what's up?

I'm trying to pick a photo from gallery and then set that photo as the image of my ImageButton. That should be pretty straight forward but somehow I'm screwing it up. This is how I'm trying: I have a fragment in which I set up my tabs and my ImageButton:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    TabHost host = (TabHost)getView().findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    host.setup();

    //Tab 1
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("Foto");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec.setIndicator("Foto");
    host.addTab(spec);

    //Tab 2
    spec = host.newTabSpec("Sentimento");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec.setIndicator("sentimento");
    host.addTab(spec);

    //Tab 3
    spec = host.newTabSpec("Medição");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);
    spec.setIndicator("Medição");
    host.addTab(spec);

    cancelBtn = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.cancel_post_btn);
    saveBtn = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.save_post_btn);
    insertPostText = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.insert_post_text);

    postImageBtn = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.post_img_btn);
    postImageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}
```

This is my onActivityResult method with my logs:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("---------", "activity result");
    if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && requestCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK){
        Log.d("-----------", "result ok");
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        postImageBtn.setImageURI(imageUri);
    } else {
        Log.d("-----------", "result not ok");
        Log.d("----------", String.valueOf(requestCode));
        Log.d("----------", String.valueOf(RESULT_OK));
    }
}
```

These are my log results:

```
03-07 14:23:50.767 30717-30717/? D/---------: activity result
03-07 14:23:50.767 30717-30717/? D/-----------: result not ok
03-07 14:23:50.767 30717-30717/? D/----------: 1
03-07 14:23:50.767 30717-30717/? D/----------: -1
```

And finally this is my android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Have you guys any idea on why is this happening?

Comment: Does gallery open ? App crashes ?

Comment: Yes, the gallery opens and no, the app doesn't crash. I can't manage to get my ImageButton updated though and I think that's because my RESULT_OK equals to -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That makes me feel really ashamed but still I need to post the answer just in case someone reaches this question. I should be comparing

```
getActivity().RESULT_OK
```

with

```
resultCode
```

so this is how it works now:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
Log.d("---------", "activity result");
if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK){
    Log.d("-----------", "result ok");
    Uri imageUri = data.getData();
    postImageBtn.setImageURI(imageUri);
} else {
    Log.d("-----------", "result not ok");
    Log.d("----------", String.valueOf(requestCode));
    Log.d("----------", String.valueOf(RESULT_OK));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your gallery intent to this:

```
 Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        if (isAdded() && pickPhoto.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null)
            startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, requestCode);
```

Which uses a `ContentProvider` style mech